# How to execute script file at startup without using any commands like ln -s or any other to be executed at first?

Tags: init.d, init

How to execute script file at startup without requiring any commands to be executed at beginning to set it up like chmod , ln -s with etc/rc.d or any other command ?

The script file should be executed at startup by just placing the script in some path.

Comment: Not really clear: "*without requiring any commands to be executed at beginning to set it up like chmod , ln -s with etc/rc.d or any other command *"? What is the command and why these requirements (whatever they are). Is this some kind of homework?

Comment: @JacobVlijm I have tried with  /etc/init.d/ to run the script but it requires to create a symlink to /etc/rc.d/ , but i wanted something like if we place script file in some path it should executed @ startup.

Comment: Startup or log in?

Comment: @JacobVlijm @ startup

Comment: Stating the init+rc system is important, also.  upstart?  systemd?  runit?  nosh? ...

Comment: So like a piece of autorun malware? Running something with system privs on startup just by dropping the file in a particular folder sounds like it would be a bad idea from the system/user perspective. By design you *should* always need to sudo some file or setting to make a third-party file autorun.

Comment: @pbhj but the hacker would have to know the directory name where auto-run scripts are placed. If he can view `rc.local` to find out the directory name, he could just insert his malware there anyway.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Oh great I posted an answer on another question with bounty ending in 8 hours and the OP hasn't signed on in 4 days and can't accept it if it works for him. It's like turning your bounty points into "dust in the wind".

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix don't worry ,on time.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting question. Thanks for pointing out files in `/etc/rc0.d` you learn something new every day!

## Create directory to drop your scripts into

First you need to create a directory of scripts you want automatically run at startup. I would suggest creating it within `/usr/local/bin` but it can be anywhere:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin/startup-scripts
```

## Modify rc.local to run all your scripts

Then type `gksu gedit /etc/rc.local` to edit the startup script that has `sudo` powers.

Before the last line that says `exit 0` copy and paste these lines:

```
for SCRIPT in /usr/local/bin/startup-scripts/*
do
    sudo chmod +x $SCRIPT
    $SCRIPT
done
```

---

Optionally, for every script in the `startup-scripts` directory, I would put in something like:

```
echo "running script xyz within /usr/local/bin/startup-scripts"
```

as this message will appear in `/var/log/syslog` file and document your system setup.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to put the command in /etc/rc.local.
Just add the command or the script path before 'exit' line.

Answer (score 1):

Easy. Edit the /etc/environment file (with admin priveleges using sudo of course) and append the directory containing your script(s) to your system path. Then, at least in Ubuntu, it's a piece of cake: type Startup Applications in the search bar and just add a new entry in the popup with the name of the script. Reboot and the magic will happen.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a crontab @reboot to run the script, it should work with any init system.

As root :

`crontab -e`

`@reboot /path/to/your/script`